# Having Trouble Applying CSS to a form

Tags: html, css, forms, button

Hello I am trying to apply CSS to this form:

```
<form action="http://example.com/result.xml" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
            <div id="search-box">
                Catalog Search:<br />
                <input type="hidden" id="rt" name="rt" value="keyword" />
                <input type="hidden" id="tp" name="tp" value="keyword" />
                <input type="text" alt="Input Box for Catalog Search" maxlength="250" 
                size="20" id="t" name="t" value=""  />
                <input type="hidden" id="ft" name="ft" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" id="l" name="l" value="9" />
                <input type="hidden" id="d" name="d" value="2" />
                <input type="hidden" id="f" name="f" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" id="av" name="av" value="" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="form-submit"  />
            </div>
            </form>
```

I am trying to style the Search button and also the input fields.  I have looked throughout Google search results and this site and have found over and over to use this format for styling the button:

```
.submit input {
    color      : #000;
    background : #ffa20f;
    border     : 2px outset #d7b9c9;
}
```

But this is not affecting my Search button at all.  How can I reference that button correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search button has a class of "form-submit" while your CSS rule is looking for a class of "submit."  If you change your CSS rule to the following, it should target the correct element:

```
.form-submit
{
  color: #000;
  background: #ffa20f;
  border: 2px outset #d7b9c9;
}
```

Comment: Nice, beat me by a minute. I need to leave jsfiddle alone lol

Comment: Funny, I was thinking that yours was the better answer because you included the working example.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are targeting the input incorrectly. Try using the following CSS which targets the ID of the parent element, and then the submit button.

```
#search-box .form-submit {
   color: #000;
   background: #ffa20f;
   border: 2px outset #d7b9c9;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WcVdn/

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you are trying to do is styling a input tag inside a container with class submit. If you want to style input type submit.

```
input[type="submit"]{
  color: #000;
  background: #ffa20f;
  border: 2px outset #d7b9c9;

}
```